# Converting a byte[] to a Bitmap

Tags: android, imageview, base64, arrays, blob

I am trying convert an 64-bit encoded string of an image(BLOB) into a Bitmap so that I may display it on an image view. The code for 64-bit decoding works fine and returns the byte-stream , but converting the returned byte-stream to a Bitmap returns null .
Please help.

```
//This statement works
byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(c.getString(TAG_PICTURE).toString().getBytes(),
Base64.DEFAULT);

//This statement returns null
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);
```

The complete code is as below :-

```
try {
            JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

            // Getting JSON Array node
            products = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCTS);

            // looping through All Contacts
            for (int i = 0; i < products.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject c = products.getJSONObject(i);     
                Double prod_price =  Double.valueOf(c.getString(TAG_PRICE));

                //The code below works as it returns the byte-array
                 byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(c.getString(TAG_PICTURE), Base64.DEFAULT);

                //The code below returns null even though the byte-stream is known 
                //from  above
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, 
                decodedString.length);

                myProductsList.add(new PRODUCT(c.getString(TAG_PRODUCT_NAME),c.getString(TAG_STORE_NAME), c.getString(TAG_OWNER_NAME), c.getString(TAG_DESCRIPTION), prod_price,bitmap));


            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
   }
```

I would appreciate a solution on this as I have spent a long time searching and am now stuck on this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to everyone who made suggestions. I found out the fundamental issue was not in the Java programming side but on the database. I had been storing images as blob data-type which tend to small for the images. Changing the datatype to mediumblob solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Change this code :

```
byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(c.getString(TAG_PICTURE).toString().getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);
```

To :

```
byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(c.getString(TAG_PICTURE), Base64.DEFAULT);
```

There is no need to call `toString` because you already use `getString`, and dont call `getBytes`, just pass the **encoded** `String` to `decode` 1st `param`.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions @Blaze Tama , I tried it and it still does not work.I have re-edited the post to accommodate your suggestions.

Comment: You welcome :) Are you sure c.getString(TAG_PICTURE) returns base64-encoded String? I use this code (my answer) and it works fine

Comment: Yes it does , the decodedString variable has 65535 bytes in total.

Comment: The encoding was previously done on the database server through the PHP statement:

$product["picture"]=base64_encode($row["picture"]);

Am able to see the base64 encoded stream when I  debug the code.